# I want to import a range that is found below a specific value

Tags: google-sheets

I'm attempting to create a metric tracking tool that is relatively simple to add new employees as they are hired. My goal is to create a template sheet that only needs the name on the sheet to be changed from "First Last" to the exact name found on the "Dispenses" sheet for the new employee's sheet to update properly. Basically, I need a formula in cell A2 (of my template sheet) that checks the name in Cell A1 of the template sheet to then import a range directly below(or including) the unique name found in the "Dispenses" sheet that includes the 2 columns containing the data for that individual. I'm willing to make any changes to the format of the template sheet, but  I can only make small additions to the Dispenses sheet (such as a second unique name for each employee to pull over the 2 columns separately).

[Metric tool example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QHLr0mNO8QYCp0bRgcDhoDarMPD0vH3WUQeArs5Kj2E/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first column of `Template`

```
=INDEX(Dispenses!A:J,,MATCH(A1,Dispenses!3:3,0))
```

In the second column `Template`

```
=INDEX(Dispenses!A:J,,MATCH(A1,Dispenses!3:3,0)+1)
```

**Or**

You could have a helper cell in `B1` with the formula

```
=MATCH(A1,Dispenses!3:3,0)-1
```

The formula row could then contain the following formula which can be repeated in as many columns as you'd like to return:

```
=INDEX(Dispenses!A:J,,$B$1+COLUMN())
```